# Why is the UITextField placeholder text decreasing in size?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have a peculiar problem in Interface Builder with placeholder text. Some of the placeholder text is smaller than the rest and I can't find a reason why. When I duplicate a UITextfield with full-sized placeholder text it changes instantly to a smaller font.

Xcode 6.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.2

[image]

Comment: Add an image link through http://imgur.com/ and share in the question itself or as a comment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a visual bug in Xcode 6. Whenever you copy an element with text, that text's font-size seems to visually be altered. However, when you build and run the app, it should show up normal on your device or simulator.

You can fix the visual bug by clicking on the copied element, going to the attributes inspector, and then changing the font-size down one and then back up one.

Comment: Good call! Thanks for the help!